# How to check if my program is compliant with a particular standard?

Tags: c++, g++, standards

I'm taking a c++ class in my school and I'm wondering if there is an easy way of telling the compiler to be more strict with my program. Particularly, I want my compiler to tell me if my program **does not** comply with i.e. c++11 standard.

I want to be understood, so here is a hypothetical situation. Let's say I wrote a program and it compiles fine. But it compiled because compiler was just nice to me and understood what I wanted to do. I want the compiler to tell me *I can compile your program, but this fragment shouldn't look like this*.

Comment: what do you mean by "standard compliant" ? note that the standard permits varying levels of 'underspecification', from platform dependent behaviour, up to undefined behaviour ... note that even standard-wise undefined behaviour could be perfectly legal under some compiler/environment combo ...

Comment: From the practical point of view - you have to select several compilers like gcc, clang, cl (Visual studio). In gcc and clang you can specift the desired standard and pedantic warning level, in VS you disable "Language Extentions" - It does not looks like you can choose specific stanrdard flavor. But if you can compile your code with all 3 compilers - it is probably more or less standard...

Answer (score 0):

> I want the compiler to tell me I can compile your program, but this fragment shouldn't look like this.

That's partially done with warnings. But however mostly on a micro compliance level only.

Inspection of bigger code part compliance is more the job of a static analysis tool. Besides most good ones of these are commercial, there is a fairly good open source project based on clang IIRC.